# Sublime Text does not launch under gksudo

Tags: 12.04, bash, sublime-text, gksudo

Sublime Text does not launch under `gksudo`. If I start it directly

```
sudo subl
```

it works, but

```
gksudo subl
```

fails.

Also, how can I get a list of programs that can run from terminal straight away (like the home environment variable in Windows)?

Comment: Silly question, but note that `gksudo` is not installed by default, is it installed? Is there an error message? What exactly do you mean by "straight away"? running an app by its name?

Comment: For me it works perfectly. I have to use `sublime` instead of `subl`, though. I noticed that `sudo sublime` starts it with the same profile (or something like that, it remembers the last opened files) like `sublime` but `gksudo sublime` opens a new one/fresh window.

Comment: @JacobVlijm straight away means without entering directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/817316/cant-start-sublime-text-with-gksu), although there is no answer about what makes sublime behave like this. In short, use `-w` argument.

As for the second question, I think you are looking for a `PATH` environment variable. [Here](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html) is some info.